# Search info_split is empty

Tags: theming, search

I need to customize the search results of a drupal 8 (8.7.0 currently) page a bit and need the node_type for this. According to [search-result.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21templates%21search-result.html.twig/8.7.x), this should be stored in `info_split.type`, but the whole variable is empty.

How can I get the node type inside the search-result.html.twig file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I'm still not sure why the fields are empty, but they the keys are certainly there. Either it is a bug in the core, or some weird behaviour of my installations.

I fixed it now manually by implementing the `preprocess_search_result` hook in `mytheme.theme`:

```php
function mytheme_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {

    $variables['type'] = $variables['result']['node']->get('type')->getString();
    $variables['nid'] = $variables['result']['node']->get('nid')->getString();

    switch ($variables['type']) {
        // some other adjustments based on the node tpye 
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe as a sidenote - I was a bit weary about a performance drop by this, but it is not noticable